# Streaming ip camera to many client monitor, udp/rtsp

Tags: udp, streaming

I need to broadcast an ipcamera to many different spot.
Now the system is alredy working but every client read the streaming directly via network. 
I want to reduce the traffic by sending just one "flow" throw a server ( still don't know which kind of technology) so the client could read the streaming from it.

I was thinking about a webpage that embed a video player, so I can reach the streaming via browser.

But my question is, if multiple browser open the website, the webserver open just one connection throw the ipcamera or one for each http request?

Comment: Does your IP camera have the ability to multicast? If so then you will want to begin your redesign around this feature. If it doesn't then you might was to consider replacing it with one that can or install a multicast server that can distribute on its behalf. Second, does your network infrastructure support IGMP snooping? If you are routing between LANs you might need your routers to support DVMRP or PIM.

Comment: Yes, I have the multicast setting, but I dont know how to use it.
I will read about it, thanks

Comment: Before enabling multicast in the device make sure that your network switches are able to prune this traffic. Your particular switches might refer to this as "multicast pruning", "IGMP snooping", or something similar. If you list the make and model here someone might be able to give you specific instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct path here is *multicast* -- one sender, many receivers. But that may not be supported by the camera, your network (read: wifi), or clients.

If all you want is to reduce the traffic and processing load on the camera, a "video proxy" application may fit the bill. (Something like shoutcast, but for video.) Make one connection to the camera, and let the app/server copy the stream to how ever many clients want it. (product recommendation are off-topic, btw.)

Comment: I saw the menu voice in the configuration panel:

-Multicast address 239.255.42.xxx
-port: 36666

I must check other setting on the router? 
And how can I "read" the stream with an android client?
I was pondering to use a raspberry pi for the client side but I just want to try the system with my phone if I can.
Thanks!